# Python 2.7 division unexpected result

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2 with `from __future__ import division` added.

I have the following variables `count = 865` and `total = 1060`.

When I use the variables `count/total` I get `1.2254335260115607`.

But my expected output of `865/1060` is not resulting in `0.8160377358490566`.

Can someone please help me understand what I am seeing this behavior and how to correct it to the expected result of `0.8160377358490566`? Thank you.

Comment: You don't seem to have said what you *are* seeing, and how it differs from what you expect.

Comment: Include your actual code, not what you think your code looks like.

Comment: You appear to be performing 1060/865, not the division you think you're performing. How you end up doing that, we can't say, since you haven't shown us anything we can run to reproduce the error.

Comment: @user2357112 ,yes error on my part. sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you have your variables assigned wrong and are dividing total by count accidentally, judging by your result